# Cannot inject HttpClient in an AngularJS/Angular hybrid app upgraded with ngUpgrade. Getting "NullInjectorError: No provider for http_HttpClient!"

Tags: angular, angularjs, httpclient, upgrade, hybrid

I have an AngularJS/Angular hybrid app updgraded with ngUpgrade. All has been working well. The new Angular components (downgraded) work fine in the AngularJS app.

However, I cannot get the HttpClient module to instantiate.

I have followed the doc and examples of this, but no success.

This is the full error:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserFeedbackService -> http_HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserFeedbackService -> http_HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for http_HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:11545:27)
    at resolveToken (core.js:12281:24)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:12226:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:12121:20)
    at resolveToken (core.js:12281:24)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:12226:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:12121:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:24381:29)
    at _createClass (core.js:24430:29)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:24400:26) '<angular-feedback-component _nghost-gam-c0="">'
```

You can see that is is actually complaining about http_HttpClient, which is strange as most cases I have seen of this report that it is HttpClient. I am not using the http_HttpClient reference anywhere.

This is app.ts:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    FeedbackComponent,
    UserFeedbackComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    FeedbackComponent,
    UserFeedbackComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    UserFeedbackService,
  ],
})
```

This is the Angular service:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

```
constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private http: HttpClient, private dialog: MatDialog) { }
```

or

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dialog: MatDialog) { }
```

The service works fine without the reference to HttpClient. It is not a problem with the service as if I try to inject HttpClient into the controller I get the same error.

FYI, this is how the hybrid app is bootstrapped in app.ts:

```
export class AppModule {

constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }

// Bootstrap using the UpgradeModule
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  console.log("Bootstrapping in Hybrid mode with Angular & AngularJS");
  const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['angularjsApp'], {strictDi: true});
});
```

Using Angular 12.2.16 and AngularJS 1.8.3.

Spent several days trying to resolve this so any help would be appreciated.

Update:

As a matter of interest, this works with the depracted @angular/http module but I still get the errors with the @angular/common/http module! Any ideas anyone?

This is the fulle service code. Http works while HttpClient gives the error:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

@Inject(HttpClient)
export class UserFeedbackService {


  constructor(private http: Http, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
 // constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private http: HttpClient, private dialog: MatDialog) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HttpClientModule should be declared after the BrowserModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule, //after BrowserModule
    UpgradeModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    FeedbackComponent,
    UserFeedbackComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    FeedbackComponent,
    UserFeedbackComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    UserFeedbackService,
  ],
})
```

Comment: Same error - I have tried it after BrowserModule and at the bottom:

Comment: Can you provide the whole code for your service that access the http call?

Comment: I did try to inject it into the component module too with the same error.

There is no code in the service apart from what I posted as I took everything out apart from the import and the constructor and on test function which does not use it but just writes a console.log. If I take the HttpClient out the function works

Comment: Added an update above - As a matter of interest, this works with the depracted @angular/http module but I still get the errors with the @angular/common/http module! Any ideas anyone?